# Why do I need to specify hostname when deploy minio in docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, minio

From [the offical doc](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/minio/minio/master/docs/orchestration/docker-swarm/docker-compose-secrets.yaml), the hostname is specified for each minio service when running in docker swarm. But from [the offical doc](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/minio/minio/master/docs/orchestration/docker-compose/docker-compose.yaml), we don't need to specify hostname in docker compose. I'd like to know the reason. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

from [docker-compose networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

so when you launch minio by leveraging docker-compose, hostname is set for you automatically by docker-compose.

the use of the hostname is needed in order to connect to the minio. for instance, this is the general usages of [adding a storage service using minio client](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-client-complete-guide.html)

```sh
mc alias set <ALIAS> <YOUR-S3-ENDPOINT> [YOUR-ACCESS-KEY] [YOUR-SECRET-KEY] [--api API-SIGNATURE]
```

when using docker-compose, you can easily switch the `<YOUR-S3-ENDPOINT>` by the docker image name of the minio server.

docker swarm behaves differently.

Comment: I run `docker-compose up`, then bash into minio1, then cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname. I turns out the hostname is just a random number 09a5f819df30, not minio1.

Comment: Btw, in docker swarm a service can access other services by service name, I don't know why a hostname is needed.